# Symfony 4 + API Plantform +LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle Bad Credential

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

Good afternoon. Please i'm using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle in a symfony 4 api project. I'm using UserProvider for Doctrine.

After Configure Doctrine User Provider, I've install and configure LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. But when i tried to athentificate using Postman on the url http://localhost:8000/api/login_check whith this JSON {"username":"ak",
"password":"ak"} I've this error: {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Bad credentials"
}.
See below my Security.yaml config file. I've read forums to tried to solve this issue but i've not yet found the solution. Can you please help me?

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\Utilisateur:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    #in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Utilisateur

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        user_checker: App\Security\UtilisateurChecker
        anonymous: true
        provider: our_db_provider         

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning All. I've found the solution of my problem. In fact, i was typing a bad User Password.

To solve this article, i've used this article https://numa-bord.com/miniblog/symfony-4-les-base-dune-gestion-des-utilisateurs-inscription-connexion-droits-dacces/
I've created au database user by using create user command implemented in the article.

After i have been connected with this previous created user sucessfully. ApiPlatform generate a web tocken for me.

## Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Have you missed a piece of configuration during [installation](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation)? I dont see the lexik one:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key:       '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem' # required for token creation
    public_key:       '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem'  # required for token verification
    pass_phrase:      'your_secret_passphrase' # required for token creation, usage of an environment variable is recommended
    token_ttl:        3600
```

Comment: I've put this configuration in my lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml file.  lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'

In .env file i've this

###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=5c2561dc331622e14a6ff0377bdb3cc0
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###